Combine date and time in Teradata if Time is an I2 Type
I am trying to combine two columns into a date and time timestamp column. However I am constantly running into a invalid timestamp error.
I ran a "help column" on my columns and found out:
My date column has a type DA with a YYYY-MM-DD format
My time column has a type i2 with a 99:99 format.
I tried this but got invalid timestamp.
CAST((CAST(t108.Evnt_Date AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || t108.Evnt_Time) AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDHHMI') AS Evnt_Tmst. 

I would like it to be one column that has the date and time so I can do date difference. From my results, an example date is 05/24/2024 but a time could just say 19 or 2000. There is no colon delimiter.

'i2' is smallint, what does your data actually look like? What would a value of 19 mean as time?  How about 8?  How do you know if a digit represents an hour or a minute?  In other words, would 1 mean 1:00AM?  12:01AM?

an example row would have an output:
evnt_date = 4/12/2024
evnt_time = 145
I know that event time is 24hr time so 145 is technically 01:45

The timestamp format doesn't match your string, try FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DDBHH:MI'

And if it still fails use trycast to avoid errors: TRYCAST((CAST(t108.Evnt_Date AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || t108.Evnt_Time) || ':00' AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AS Evnt_Tmst (TryCast doesn't support FORMAT, thus the added seconds)

First of all you want to get from separated date and time to a timestamp, i.e. the combination of date and time.
Then your time is not stored in a TIME column, unfortunately, but in an integer column. That integer column contains a number of which the two right-most digits are minutes and the remaining digits to their left hours. This means that we must calculate the real time. In total minutes that is hours * 60 + minutes.
Looking up the appropriate functions and operators in Teradata, I come up with
CAST (t108.evnt_date AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + 
  ((t108.evnt_time / 100 * 60) + (t108.evnt_time MOD 100)) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE


Thank you for your help. If I broke up my timestamp from two different tables
(a.timestamp and b.timestamp) would I be able to do a date diff?

I am not a Teradata developer. From what I see on the Internet, you should be able to cast the timestamps to dates and then simply subtract one from the other to get the difference in days.

As an FYI, because you're converting the "timestamp" to an interval, this will "work" for numeric values that aren't actually a time. For ex, if you have 2024-06-12 as the date, and 2500 as the time, this will add 25 hours to the date, returning 2024-06-13 01:00

Oh, weird. (I am not converting a timestamp to an interval, by the way, I am adding an interval to a timestamp, so as to get an updated timestamp.)
